# Can I load multiple SWF file one by one?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

Can I load multiple SWF file? Is it possible to load a child swf files after loading main window, Action should be in background?

Comment: You can take a look at LoaderMax http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/

Answer (score 0):

You sure can. Just use the standard [Loader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html) class like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("completeHandler: " + event);
}

// other functions..
```

This way you can load a file, and with just a little tweak you can load them either simultaneous or asynchronous.

Just put some efforts and it will all work out well.